# Inserting LaTeX code into LaTeX

Tags: verbatim

I have a problem with adding text into a LaTeX document. I have a LaTeX document about LaTeX and I need to insert some code snippets. I need to add "\usepackage{musixtex}" as a text, which should be displayed as a text. Do you know how?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819689/latex-inserting-latex-code-into-latex?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `\verb` like this:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
Example: \verb!\usepackage{musixtex}!
\end{document}
```

<sub>*Edits by Speravir and Sam Whited:*</sub>

There is also a starred version, which makes the spaces visible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\verb|\LaTeX vs. \LaTeX\ or \LaTeX{} \dots|

\verb*|\LaTeX vs. \LaTeX\ or \LaTeX{} \dots|

\LaTeX vs. \LaTeX\ or \LaTeX{} \dots
\end{document}
```

#### Multiline

If you end up with more than a short, one line, phrase you might also try the `verbatim` (built in) or `Verbatim` (an improved version located in the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package) environments.

eg.

```
\begin{verbatim}
  Some LaTeX code here
  Which can be multiple lines
  \usepackage{musixtex}
  \begin{music}\nostartrule
  \instrumentnumber{1}

  ...
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :-( it show me only "musixtex"

Comment: modified the example to be testable. It works for me... Try compiling the above as-is.

Comment: it works in this sample, but I am using it in beamer presentation and here it is not working

Comment: Ah, it is solved now, I have forgotten to make frame "fragile", thanks

Answer (score 22):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
}

\begin{document}
This is inline \lstinline!\TeX! and the following is displayed 

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

If you need source code and rendered output side by side, use `showexpl` (no need to load `listings` because `showexpl` loads `listings` automatically) as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset
{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
}

\begin{document}
This is inline \lstinline!\TeX! and the following is displayed 

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b,preset=\centering,width=0.5\linewidth]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And for those who want to specify the language for each listing: You have to use `\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]...\end{lstlisting}`. Note the curly brackets around the language.