# How to typeset LaTeX code inside a Table environment?

Tags: verbatim, best-practices, code

I wanted to typeset LaTeX code directly into my document, but without it doing something, i.e., I just want to show my code in the output.

Now, I know there is the `verbatim` environment for code, as well as the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package for this, but I am wondering what the best method for typesetting LaTeX code directly is (if there is one), without needing any extra packages.

A few days ago I tried to do it inside a table, and I came up with this question: [Print small TeX code verbatim and render it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it/128441#128441)

but still, they managed to do something different, as it automatically included the showcase.

I just want to be able to write a LaTeX code snippet easily and inside a normal environment, say, `tables`. What is the best way to do it?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbhp]
\centering
\caption{Citing with FEUPPHDTESES.STY}\label{tab:Citing}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Command & Result\\
\midrule
\texttt{citeplist}  & \verb\citeplist{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse,espinoza2012optimization}\\
\texttt{citet}          & \verb\citet{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse,espinoza2012optimization}\\
\texttt{citep}          & \verb\citep{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse,espinoza2012optimization}\\
\texttt{citeyear}       & \verb\citeyear{peel_epidemiology_2011}\\
\texttt{citeauthor} & \verb\citeauthor{peel_epidemiology_2011}\\
\texttt{citetlist}  & \verb\citetlist{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse,espinoza2012optimization}\\
\texttt{citeplist}  & \verb\citeplist{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse,espinoza2012optimization}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the standard `\verb` command and the `verbatim` environment? They are available without extra packages... of course they have no syntax highlighting...

Comment: @cgnieder I tried both of them, they didn't seem to work inside the `table` environment.  I'll upload a MWE.

Comment: `\verb` syntax is `\verb<marker><code><marker>` where `<code>` may not contain `<marker>`, e.g., `\verb+&$%#+`.

Comment: This is because `\verb` and friends are fragile; see the related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203/how-to-obtain-verbatim-text-in-a-footnote

Comment: @SeanAllred yeap, I also got to that question.  But mine still remains, if `\verb` cannot be used and neither `begin{verbatim}`... how can I use it?  Most importantly, how did the guys that wrote `The LaTeX Companion` did it?

Comment: If you use `\verb` correctly, you'd have no problem: `\verb|\citeyear{peel_epidemiology_2011}|`

Comment: Thanks @egreg That was it, it works now!.  Nevertheless, what should I use: `verbatim` or `verb`? What are the main differences or advantages?

Comment: `verbatim` makes a text block the whole `\linewidth` wide; `\verb<char><text><char>` (where `<char>` is not used in `<text>` takes just the space it needs. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86568/what-are-the-differences-between-verb-and-verbatim

Comment: @egreg I actually get an error if I use `\begin{verbatim}\citeplist{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse,espinoza2012optimization}\end{verbatim}`

Comment: @MarioS.E. Obviously: a `verbatim` environment doesn't make any sense in a cell declared to belong to an `l` column.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand why not.  It is impossible to use `verbatim` inside a table or is it impossible to use `verbatim` inside an `l` column?

Comment: Related [Inserting LaTeX code into LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49131/15717), [LaTeX Verbatim Source Code Beside the Typeset Output](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60294/15717) and [Any way to show LaTeX example code *and* execute it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110349/15717)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The syntax for `\verb` is

```
\verb<char><text><char>
```

where `<char>` should be a (non special) character not found in `<text>`. Most often `|` or `+` are used for `<char>`.

A `verbatim` environment doesn't make sense in a table cell belonging to a column declared as `l`, `c` or `r`, just like a `quote` environment doesn't make sense in the argument to `\mbox`.

If you have multiline verbatim to be used in a cell column, you need to use a `p` column, but with some adjustments.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{>{\topsep=0pt\@minipagetrue}p{#1}<{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\command}[1]{\texttt{\string#1}}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Command & Example\
\midrule
\command{\citeplist}
 & \verb|\citeplist{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse}|
 \\
\command{\citet}
 & \verb|\citet{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse}|
 \\
\command{\citep}
 & \verb|\citep{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse}|
 \\
\command{\citeyear}
 & \verb|\citeyear{peel_epidemiology_2011}|
 \\
\command{\citeauthor}
 & \verb|\citeauthor{peel_epidemiology_2011}|
 \\
\command{\citetlist}
 & \verb|\citetlist{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse}|
 \\
\command{\citeplist}
 & \verb|\citeplist{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse}|
 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lV{280pt}}
\toprule
Command & Example\\
\midrule
\command{\citeplist} &
\begin{verbatim}
\citeplist{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse,
           espinoza2012optimization
\end{verbatim}
\\
\command{\citet} &
\begin{verbatim}
\citet{peel_epidemiology_2011,espinoza2012inverse,
       espinoza2012optimization
\end{verbatim}
\\
\command{\citeyear} &
\begin{verbatim}
\citeyear{peel_epidemiology_2011}
\end{verbatim}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]