# How to remove leading spaces before and after verbatim inside a table cell?

Tags: tables, spacing, paragraphs, verbatim, vspace

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,etoolbox,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily}p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
    \vspace{-6pt} % NOTE!
    \begin{verbatim}
lines within verbatim 
environment. Let's add
some more lines
    \end{verbatim}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip} % NOTE!
    ordinary lines out of
    verbatim environment 
    &
  \lipsum[1][1-2]\\
  \end{tabular}\\
\end{table}

\noindent Before verbatim
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
\end{verbatim}
After verbatim

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I looked for a solution that removes spaces before and after `verbatim`. Yes I found it (see line `\preto`) but, as you can see from the example above, it will not work in `tabular`'s cell if I remove `\vspace`s. I empirically "hacked" the right values but I would like to understand what do I wrong. I want to use `\verbatim` just *as is* and see no odd leading spaces before or after in case of table cells.

Comment: To make the MWE compilable, the `array`, `etoolbox` and `lipsum` packages are missing.

Comment: The new `V` type column defined by [egreg in an answer to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140631/134144) should also work in your case.

Comment: I don't want to shift/affect all the column by defining some new type. Why couldn't it be solved just by affecting verbatim?

Comment: You can use \verb instead.  No extra lines there.

Comment: `verb|something|` doesn't allow line breaks.