# Command \textbackslash invalid in math mode

Tags: math-mode, formatting, symbols

I'm trying to write LaTeX code in my document. Could someone help me with this error message:

> LaTeX Warning: Command `\textbackslash` invalid in math mode on input line 4.

```latex
{\fontsize{10pt}{12.0pt}\selectfont $\textbackslash$ def$\textbackslash$ cp$ \{ $ $\textbackslash$ textit$ \{ $ cp.$ \} $ $ \} $ \ \par}\par
```

Answer (score 12):

`\textbackslash` is a *text*-mode command, so it does not work in math-mode (as you may have noticed) because math fonts are wildly different from text fonts, so the characters are set up differently, so they are not at all compatible. in math-mode you'd use `\backslash` if you wanted the backslash *math* symbol.

Though your command:

```latex
$\textbackslash$def $\textbackslash$cp $\{$ $\textbackslash$ textit$ \{ $ cp.$ \} $ $ \} $
```

looks a lot like you are trying to typeset some LaTeX command. Then just use `\verb`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\verb|\def\cp{\textit{cp.}}|
\end{document}
```

> [image]

As a rule of thumb: if it's *too* complicated, you're doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Your guess is extremely great...+1

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am so fresh in LaTex that you can almost smell me still baking. I am trying to help my wife to convert source code to PDF file. She prepares thesis and she is stuck with converting source code to PDF

Comment: @Tayco You're welcome. Don't worry about being new to LaTeX: we all started somewhere :-) As I said, if it's too complicated (with too complicated I mean you have to drastically change the input to get what you want), then there is something wrong. You can easily write LaTeX code verbatim (no changes in the code). See here, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49131/134574 and here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing. And if you have any problems, feel free to ask a new question. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: It sounds so easy dear Phelype when you say it :) I used Overleaf and erro notification changed suddenly. Now it says Package microtype Warning: Redefining noligatures set `no ligatures' on input line 39.

Comment: @Tayco Oh, I know it's not easy. I was there not so long ago (I use LaTeX since 2015). But you get used to it. That is not an error, just a warning, so you can (usually) ignore it. In this case, the warning seems just to inform you, so you don't need to worry. Though when you have a problem, please ask [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Comments are not intended for lengthy discussions and might be deleted. Thanks!

Comment: For converting source code to pdf, look into the `listings` package.  Or `minted`.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE... Why you need `\textbackslash` inside math, is there any intentional? You can use just `\backslash` inside math...

Comment: Thanks for asking. This is not a math work, this is text work.